# How to get value of an objet in an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Hope you're well. I need your help today.

I've got on my page a  which contains attributes. One of these, named data-params, contains an object. In this object we've got a lot of data and I want to get only one value. I tried to use `Object.keys` OR `element.attributes` but it doesn't work. I really don't know how and where to search. It seems this object looks like JSON.

By the way thanks a lot by advance for your help and happy coding :)

PS : Here the code of the  :

`<div id="wpws-live" data-params="{&quot;cache_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/www.ecommerce-nation.fr\/wp-content\/plugins\/wpwebinarsystem\/cache\/webinar_808227d5-f2e7-480d-b438-19f2d0e6feb8_v2.json&quot;,&quot;secure_room_name&quot;:&quot;96269b8f-3ce6-47f2-8c64-92e62291799a&quot;,&quot;secure_room_key&quot;:&quot;e2324107-c6b6-42a8-8a79-a5bdfc26ac32&quot;,&quot;reduce_server_load&quot;:false,&quot;webinar_time_in_seconds&quot;:3465657,&quot;webinar_start_time&quot;:1591194600,&quot;duration&quot;:3600,&quot;timezone_offset&quot;:120,&quot;attendee&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:477,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;blablablo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;blablablo@yopmail.com&quot;,&quot;is_team_member&quot;:true},&quot;translations&quot;:{&quot;webinarSummaryStartingTimer&quot;:&quot;Commence \u00e0&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryStartWebinar&quot;:&quot;Lancer le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryStopBroadcasting&quot;:&quot;Stopper le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryLogout&quot;:&quot;Quitter le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerDays&quot;:&quot;jours&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerHours&quot;:&quot;heures&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerMinutes&quot;:&quot;minutes&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerSeconds&quot;:&quot;secondes&quot;,&quot;webinarTabsPeople&quot;:&quot;Explorateurs&quot;,&quot;webinarChatEmpty&quot;:&quot;Personne n'a encore parl\u00e9... Lancez la conversation !&quot;,&quot;webinarChatPlaceholder&quot;:&quot;Appuyez sur Entrer pour envoyer votre message&quot;,&quot;webinarChatMenuDelete&quot</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></main></div>`

Comment: Neither the HTML nor the string object that you pasted here are valid.

Comment: if you would use jquery you could just do 
var val = $("#elementId").data("params");

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Hello ! I know but I am limited to 30000 characters so I cut it off. Thanks for your comment !

Comment: @zetawars Hello ! Thanks for your comment but i want a specific data in this object ;)

Comment: I guess if that's the case, you'll need to more clearly specify exactly what it is you're looking for.

Comment: @user2366842 Hello ! Thanks for your comment, yes pretty hard to be clear with that code :( I try to get this value : blablablo@yopmail.com. If that can help you :)

Comment: Assuming that you have the string object from `data-params` in your JavaScript, have you tried doing something like `JSON.parse(obj.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-params` string seems to be incomplete. I did some "repair work" on it and managed to process it as shown below:

```js
let d=document.querySelector("#wpws-live"),jsn=d.dataset.params,
    o=JSON.parse(jsn);
d.textContent=o.attendee.email;  // display a single property in the div
console.log(o);                  // list the whole object with all its properties
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 80% !important;}
```

```html
<div id="wpws-live" data-params="{&quot;cache_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/www.ecommerce-nation.fr\/wp-content\/plugins\/wpwebinarsystem\/cache\/webinar_808227d5-f2e7-480d-b438-19f2d0e6feb8_v2.json&quot;,&quot;secure_room_name&quot;:&quot;96269b8f-3ce6-47f2-8c64-92e62291799a&quot;,&quot;secure_room_key&quot;:&quot;e2324107-c6b6-42a8-8a79-a5bdfc26ac32&quot;,&quot;reduce_server_load&quot;:false,&quot;webinar_time_in_seconds&quot;:3465657,&quot;webinar_start_time&quot;:1591194600,&quot;duration&quot;:3600,&quot;timezone_offset&quot;:120,&quot;attendee&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:477,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;blablablo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;blablablo@yopmail.com&quot;,&quot;is_team_member&quot;:true},&quot;translations&quot;:{&quot;webinarSummaryStartingTimer&quot;:&quot;Commence \u00e0&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryStartWebinar&quot;:&quot;Lancer le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryStopBroadcasting&quot;:&quot;Stopper le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarSummaryLogout&quot;:&quot;Quitter le webinar&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerDays&quot;:&quot;jours&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerHours&quot;:&quot;heures&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerMinutes&quot;:&quot;minutes&quot;,&quot;webinarTimerSeconds&quot;:&quot;secondes&quot;,&quot;webinarTabsPeople&quot;:&quot;Explorateurs&quot;,&quot;webinarChatEmpty&quot;:&quot;Personne n'a encore parl\u00e9... Lancez la conversation !&quot;,&quot;webinarChatPlaceholder&quot;:&quot;Appuyez sur Entrer pour envoyer votre message&quot;}}">the div</div>
```